# Switch off Run-Time check in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, runtime

I have the problem, to get a failed run-time check in Visual C++ 2008 because of casting a too big number to a smaller type. The failure is in an external dll, so I can not fix it there. So how can I switch off this run time check for an external project.

Comment: Debugger wrote:
Run-Time Check Failure #1 - A cast to a smaller data type has caused a loss of data.  If this was intentional, you should mask the source of the cast with the appropriate bitmask.  For example:  

 char c = (i & 0xFF);

Answer (score 3):

If the cast (and check) is happening in this DLL which you can't recompile, then you can't easily turn off the check.

The only thing you could do is change the data which you pass to the DLL to avoid the problem.   Or patch the binary to disable the check, which probably wouldn't be terribly difficult as that sort of thing goes - are you good with a disassembler?

Answer (score 2):

The Runtime check depends on the option /RTC c able to find in Visual Studio Configuration Properties of the project, C/C++ Code generation, "Smaller Type Check". You should switch off this, and recompile.

Answer (score -1):

You can always just turn off the cast to smaller type check in the project settings.

If that doesn't work as the check is compiled into the dll, then you can try linking to the non-debug version dll, as the check can only be on for debug "optimized" build. It might affect your debugging though of course.